# Regex - Allow Numbers 0-9, Backsapce and 1 dot Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function which acts on keydown event and I want it to allow only numbers, backspace and 1 dot. I can't make it work. Here is what I tried:

```
$('#input[type="number"]').keydown(function(e) {

            this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
            var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9.,\b]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                console.log('stop now')
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
});
```

It still prevents dot, but allows numbers. I think my Regex is wrong and needs a tweak.

The comment is gone, but some user suggested that it could be to do with the escaping of the `.` and `,` ?? Any ideas?

Comment: When writing regex I use https://www.debuggex.com/ to visualize the flow.

Comment: If you need ***only one dot*** there is an error in your regex because the `+` symbol is a quantifier and means **between one and unlimited occurrences**

Comment: You say "want it to allow only numbers". Then you say "still allows numbers". Do you want to allow numbers, or not? Why do you have a comma in your regexp?

Comment: @torazaburo -yes I do. I meant my code allows numbers to pass OK as a result of the above. It still prevents a dot from passing. I want to try and make a regex expression that will only allow numbers, backspace and 1 occurrence of a dot..any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `keypress` insetead of the `keydown` event. There are different charcodes sent for some keys for the `keydown` event. The dot is one of them, sending code `190` instead of the ASCII `46`. You can play around with it [here](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instead of using regex. I think This will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">  
  <script type="text/javascript" language="jscript">
      function fncInputNumericValuesOnly() {
          if (!(event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 50 || event.keyCode == 51 || event.keyCode == 52 || event.keyCode == 53 || event.keyCode == 54 || event.keyCode == 55 || event.keyCode == 56 || event.keyCode == 57))
          {
              event.returnValue = false;
          }
      }
</script>
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" onkeypress="fncInputNumericValuesOnly()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
    </div>  
    </form>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that tip lead me to the answer I posted! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but this would work.

edit: click run code snippit before you downvote

```js
var onlySome = restrictKeys([8,190]) // allow the dot

// decorate the jquery function with some functional goodness
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(onlySome(function(e) {
  stackLog(['key alowed', e.which, String.fromCharCode(e.which)]);
}));

// functional function to partially apply restricted keys and callback functiion
function restrictKeys(keys) {
  return function(fn) {
    return function(e) {
      // all codes between 48 and 57 are number and cool to leave in, then just filter out our array
      if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && keys.indexOf(e.which) < 0) {
        stackLog(['nope', e.which, String.fromCharCode(e.which)]);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false
      }
      return fn.call(this, e);
    }
  }
}

function stackLog(log) {
  var _console = document.querySelector('#console');
  _console.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(log) + '\n' + _console.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text here">
<pre id="console"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried something like that?
Of course is not perfect but you can assume it as a starter point:

```js
var whitelist = /^\d+\.?\d+?[\b]?$/;

function testInput() {
  var val = document.getElementById('val').value;
  var res = document.getElementById('res');
  
  if(whitelist.test(val)) {
     res.innerText = 'YEP';
  } else {
     res.innerText = 'NOOPE';
  }  
}
```

```html
<input onchange="testInput()" type="text" id="val"/>

<h1 id="res"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks, but how would that work in context to the above. Would I set that as a the regex and do some sort of `.match(whitelist)` - great if you have a working fiddle or example?

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes a little late but here I've changed your code to something which may work for you:

```
var valid_value = '';
$('#input[type="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
        var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/);
        if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
            this.value = valid_value;
            console.log('stop now');
        } else {
            valid_value = this.value;
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not work for me when I try using your regex in my code. Right now I would settle for just allowing numbers and periods..does not matter for more than 1 `.` if that is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with in the end. A little manual but does the trick!

```
$('#input[type="number"]').keydown(function(e) {

         if (!(e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 48 || e.keyCode == 49 || e.keyCode == 50 || e.keyCode == 51 || e.keyCode == 52 || e.keyCode == 53 || e.keyCode == 54 || e.keyCode == 55 || e.keyCode == 56 || e.keyCode == 57)) {
                e.returnValue = false;
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
});
```